# Code Coverage not reaching 100%

Tags: apex, unit-test

I created a trigger and 2 test classes. They only cover 73% and I can't figure out why. The trigger updates the field "Email_Opt_In__c" on the Lead/Contact that is a campaignMember with a "Registered" Status.

```
trigger CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (after insert,after update) {
    Set<Id> LeadSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> ContSet = new Set<Id>();    
        for (CampaignMember cm:Trigger.new){
            if ((cm.LeadId<>Null)&& (cm.Status=='Registered'))
                   LeadSet.add(cm.LeadId);
               else 
                if ((cm.ContactId<>Null)&& (cm.Status=='Registered'))
                       ContSet.add(cm.ContactId);

        }

        Map<Id,Lead> LeadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT Id,Email_Opt_In__c FROM Lead WHERE Id In :LeadSet]);
        Map<Id,Contact> ContMap = new Map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Id,Email_Opt_In__c FROM Contact WHERE Id In :ContSet]);

        for(Lead ld:LeadMap.values())
            ld.Email_Opt_In__c = True;

        for (Contact cont:ContMap.values())
            cont.Email_Opt_In__c=True;

        update LeadMap.values();
        update ContMap.values();
}
```

These are the test classes:

```
@isTest
public class CampMemberLeadTestClass {
   static TestMethod void TestCampMemberTrigger(){
    Campaign cp=new Campaign(Name='Test');
    insert cp;
    Lead[] LeadToCreate = new Lead[]{};    

    CampaignMember[] CMToCreate = new CampaignMember[]{};

        for (integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            Lead ld=new Lead(lastname='Test2',Company='Test3',Status='New');
            LeadToCreate.add(ld);
        }
        insert LeadToCreate;
        System.debug('Lead Id testing:' + LeadToCreate[0].Id);     

        for (integer i=0;i<200;i++){
           CampaignMember cm= new CampaignMember(LeadId=LeadToCreate[i].Id,CampaignId=cp.Id,Status='Registered');    
           CMToCreate.add(cm);
        }    

   insert CMToCreate;
   System.debug('Campaign Member Id:' + CMToCreate[0].Id);
   } 
}

@isTest
public class CampMemberContactTest {
    static TestMethod Void CampMemberContacttest(){
        Campaign cp=new Campaign(Name='Test');
        insert cp;
        Contact[] ContactToCreate = new Contact[]{};

        for (integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            Contact cont=new Contact(lastname='Test2');
            ContactToCreate.add(cont);
        }
        insert ContactToCreate;
        System.debug('Contact Id:' + ContactToCreate[0].Id);
        CampaignMember[] CMToCreate = new CampaignMember[]{};

         for (integer i=0;i<200;i++){
           CampaignMember cm= new CampaignMember(ContactId=ContactToCreate[i].Id,CampaignId=cp.Id,Status='Registered');    
           CMToCreate.add(cm);
        }
    insert CMToCreate;

    }

}
```

The lines from my trigger that are not being tested according to the log are:
line 6:  LeadSet.add(cm.LeadId);
line 9:  ContSet.add(cm.ContactId);
line 17: ld.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
line 18: cont.Email_Opt_In__c=True;

Thanks!
[image: lines not covered]

Comment: **1.** You never assert anything :( **2.** The line numbers you provided don't make sense, because there's a for loop in between the two uncovered lines you provided. **3.** if LeadSet.add(cm.LeadId); is never executed, then LeadMap will be empty, and that's why your line 17 isn't executing

Comment: What would you change in the code so I can reach 100% code coverage? Either in the test classes or the trigger.

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't ever be changing your trigger code so that you can get 100% coverage lol...I'll post an answer in a sec though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get better code coverage, by the way, if you reorganize your code. Observe:

```
trigger CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(CampaignMember record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Status == 'Registered') {
            idSet.add(record.ContactId==null? record.LeadId: record.ContactId);
        }
    }
    Id[] values = new List<Id>(idSet);
    values.sort();
    SObject[] records = new SObject[0];
    for(Id recordId: values) {
        records.add(recordId.getSObjectType().newSObject(recordId));
    }
    for(SObject record: records) {
        records.put('Email_Opt_In__c',true);
    }
    update records;
}
```

I use some nifty tricks here, which I'll outline. First, I use a ternary on line 5, which is covered with contacts or leads. This removes the initial if statement requirement to cover both objects. Then, I sort the ID values to get leads and contacts next to each other, and use some dynamic code to take advantage of the fact that the field name is the same for both objects, and since I have the ID of the record, I don't need to query for existing records (they are guaranteed to exist at the moment the trigger executes).

You really should be using "assertions" as well, so you'd probably want to do something like:

```
ContactToCreate = [SELECT Email_Opt_In__c FROM Contact];
for(Contact record: ContactToCreate) {
    System.assert(record.Email_Opt_In__c);
}
```

If your code isn't working right, you'll get an error message and the test will fail. For what it's worth, it seems kind of buggy that your code isn't reaching 100% coverage with those tests, because it looks correct, although you really should be wrapping your if statement blocks with curly braces ( `if(...) { ... }` ).

Try simply re-ordering your code like I've suggested and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox! With your Code and knowing that I had to create a CampaignMember Status for the Campaign I had already created, my issues was resolved and I got 100% code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you actually add assert statements so that your tests are actually testing your code.

Anyway, these two lines:

```
ld.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
cont.Email_Opt_In__c=True;
```

aren't being executed because your containers (LeadMap and ContMap) are empty, so LeadMap.values() and ContMap.values() are empty lists - this is due to the fact that the first two uncovered lines:

```
LeadSet.add(cm.LeadId);
ContSet.add(cm.ContactId);
```

are responsible for populating the containers. If they're not being executed, the containers won't have any elements. I would add debug code to make sure all of these are true, then you will have 100% coverage:

```
cm.LeadId<>Null
cm.Status=='Registered'
cm.ContactId<>Null
```

Comment: Could you tell me what lines to add and where? I tried adding a system assert to check that LeadToCreate wasn't Null and another one checking that the Campaign Member Status was Registered but the test class passed and the code coverage is still the same.
Thanks again!